# Airflow - NameError: name 'ti' is not defined

Tags: python, airflow, spark-submit

I am trying to execute a Airflow script that consists of a couple of functions. I want to pass the value of 'program_no' as an argument in spark submit request which I am getting in my DAG from an api call via context in get_conf method. I am trying to pass like {ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='parameterized_task')} but I am getting an error - NameError: name 'ti' is not defined. Please help how to resolve this issue?
I have also tried to pass {prog_no} instead of {ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='parameterized_task')} but getting same error - prog_no not defined

```py
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".py", ""),
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2023, 12, 21),
    schedule_interval=None,
    description='Event based job for calculating missed sales based allowances for retroactive program setup'
)

def get_conf(**context):
    global prog_no
    #ti = context['ti']
    prog_no = context['dag_run'].conf['program_no']
    return prog_no

parameterized_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="parameterized_task",
        python_callable=get_conf,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
    )    

sparkway_request = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='sparkway_request',
        endpoint=Variable.get('sparkway_api_endpoint'),
        method="POST",
        http_conn_id="SPARKWAY_CONN",
        data=json.dumps({
            "cmd": "sparkway-submit --master kubernetes --job-name spark-allowance-calculation --class com.xxx.CalculationApplication --spark-app s3a://xyz.jar --arguments SuspendedProgramStatus --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 3G --driver-memory 3G",
            "arguments": f"{dag.latest_execution_date},{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='parameterized_task')}",
            "type": "job"
        }),
        headers={
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {Variable.get('sparkway_token')}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": Variable.get('sparkway_csrf_token')
        },
        response_check=lambda response: handle_sparkway_response(response),
        log_response=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

parameterized_task >> sparkway_request

Comment: Well, you've commented out the only line that would define `ti`…!? (And it would be a different scope anyway.)

Comment: @deceze even without commenting ti line, I am getting the same error. Any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

`ti` will not be defined as it can only be accessible that way using jinja templating. I'm not sure if `SimpleHttpOperator` support this but you can try this instead

```
    data=json.dumps({
        "cmd": "sparkway-submit ........",
        "arguments": "{{ execution_date }},{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='parameterized_task', key='program_no') }}",
        "type": "job"
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

this way accessing ti inside the jinja template should work:

```html
        data=json.dumps({
            "cmd": "sparkway-submit --master kubernetes --job-name spark-allowance-calculation --class com.xxx.CalculationApplication --spark-app s3a://xyz.jar --arguments SuspendedProgramStatus --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 2 --executor-memory 3G --driver-memory 3G",
            "arguments": f"{dag.latest_execution_date}, {{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=["parameterized_task"][0]) }}",
            "type": "job"
        }),
```